# Как закешировать всю базу данных MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, кэширование

Можно ли закешировать всю базу данных MS SQL SERVER и писать обычные sql запросы, но что б данные брались и записывались из оперативной памяти и как это сделать?
Оперативной памяти достаточно для кеширования всей базы.

Comment: Если 2014 и лучше, то Hekaton Engine.

Answer (score 3):

Для обычных таблиц все достаточно просто:

SQL Server достаточно агрессивно использует кэширование. При достаточно большом объеме оперативной памяти данные будут читаться именно из кэша, а не из файлов на диске.

Это достаточно легко проверить, включив статистику IO перед запросом:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

SELECT * FROM ...

SET STATISTICS IO OFF
```

и проверив значение physical reads - реальных чтений с диска.

С записью чуть сложнее. Дело в том, что транзакции в SQL Server следуют принципам [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID), где D - это Durable. Это выражается в том, что SQL Server пытается сохранить на диск изменения до того, как он скажет клиенту "да, транзакция закоммитана!".

Изменения сохраняются в Log-файл (сразу же, во время выполнения запроса) и в Data-файл (примерно раз в минуту, в фоне). Основную задержку дает именно запись в Log.

Запись в лог можно минимизировать:

```
USE master ;  
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;
```

и отложить:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET DELAYED_DURABILITY = FORCED
```

Но полностью от нее избавится нельзя.

Поэтому для данных, которые хочется обрабатывать именно в памяти, в SQL Server 2016 / Azure добавили фичу [In-Memory OLTP (In-Memory Optimization)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133186.aspx), которая позволяет принудительно держать обрабатываемые данные в памяти, компилировать хранимки для работы с ними в нативный код, и дает прочие интересные плюшки, но накладывает [некоторые ограничения на поддерживаемые операции на данными](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn246937.aspx). Если обработка в памяти для вас критична - посмотрите в сторону In-Memory OLTP.